# ReactJS = array mapping not showing

Tags: reactjs

I want to ask about array mapping.

So, I have data in the api that looks like this when in the console.

[image]

// The code for the fetch is like this

```
const [listCategory, setListCategory] = useState([]);

    const getListCategoryPoi = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        getCategoryPoi()
          .then((res) => {
            setListCategory(res[1].map((item) => item.data.features));
            console.log(res[1].map((item) => item.data.features));
            console.log(res[1].map((item) => item.data.features[0]));
          })
          .catch((reject) => {
            console.log(reject);
          })
          .finally(setIsLoading(false));
      };
```

// And the code to display the data like this when using .map

```
  {listCategory.map((item, index) => (
    <p key={index}>{item.category}</p>
  ))}
```

However, when I look in the browser it doesn't show up.

[image]

My question is, *how to display the data category if the data in the console looks like the first image*? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the problem in comment:

```
{listCategory[0]?.map(item, index) => ( 
    <p key={index}>{item.category}</p>
)}
```

The issue is that before fetching data from API, `listCategory` is empty so `listCategory[0]` is `undefined` and `undefined` does not have a map function

`?.` is optional chaining. Read here: [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: bless you, its work dude and not blank white again.

Answer (score 1):

According to the console log, your output is like this

```
[
  [
    { category: 'Airport', jumlah_poi: 308 },
    { category: 'Amusement Park', jumlah_poi: 3873 },
    //... and the rest of data
  ],
];
```

I assume that is the value of listCategory so your code to display data will be like this

```
{listCategory[0].map((item, index) => (
    <p key={index}>{item.category}</p>
  ))}
```

Comment: oh w8, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" and blank white

Answer (score 0):

I think You should return the paragraph tag

```
{listCategory[0].map(item, index) => ( 
  return( 
    <p key={index}>{item.category}</p>
  ))}
```

Comment: Blank white, and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"on the line listCategory[0].map

Comment: what does it shows you when you do console.log(listCategoty);  ?